# Property or Method to obtain information about a collection?

Tags: c#, functions, properties

Suppose I have a `MyList` class which extends `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` where `MyObject` has the `Boolean` Property `Enabled`.

Let's say I want the number of `MyObject` objects that have the Property `Enabled` equal to `true`.

Should define this as a Property or a Method?

In `MyList` class, should I use:

```
public int GetNumEnabledMyObjects(){
    return this.Count(o => o.Enabled == true);
}
```

or

```
public int NumEnabledMyObjects {
    get {
        return this.Count(o => o.Enabled == true);
    }
}
```

I looked at [Properties vs. Methods in MSDN Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d%28VS.71%29.aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1) and I'm leaning towards a method since it might be considered expensive enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My vote is to make it a method.  [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) is `O(n)`, and I think you'd be hard pressed to find a property anywhere in Linq for a number of reasons, including Big O.

In any case, most clients expect Properties to involve looking up some state, and/or involve minimal processing (e.g. output formatting).  Retrieving a stored `Count` would qualify; iterating over a collection does not.

Comment: Thanks, so if I was to modify `MyList` so that the inherited methods (ex. `Add`, `Remove`, etc.) updated a `EnabledCount` variable, would that be a better practice than the method?

Comment: I don't know if that breaks Linq or not.  Collections in Linq don't maintain a count, and since the benefits of such a thing are obvious, I can only assume that it's not technically feasible to do so, given Linq's processing pipeline architecture (i.e. it prefers to deal with plain ol' collections).

Comment: `Count()` in Linq would only work with a stored value anyway if you didn't supply it with a predicate.

Comment: But what about `ObservableCollection.Items.Count`? Supposedly that's an O(1) operation too, if I wanted the number of items with no condition. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132435(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, no.  The `Items` property is `O(1)` (probably because it merely exposes a reference to the internal Items collection), not `Count()`.

Comment: Might be a chicken and egg thing... but the reason LINQ ships with no properties is that "extension properties" do not exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx.  One big limitation of extension methods: they don't have access to the internal members of a class.  They're just syntactic sugar over static methods.  I assume that extension properties would have the same limitation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not sure that's relevant.  I'm addressing your statement "you'd be hard pressed to find"... in fact I can assure you that there are none, because LINQ is implemented using extension methods, and extension properties do not exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt: To me, extension properties imply access to the class internals.  Even automatic properties require a backing field under the hood.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't see how that is any more true for extension properties than extension methods.  One could certainly imagine an `IsEmpty` LINQ property -- it can be simply implemented using only the public interface.  But the cost would be misleading (except when the underlying object implements `IList` and has an O(1) `Count` property).

Comment: @BenVoigt `IsEmpty` can be implemented in O(1): `return !collection.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()`, [just like the non-delegate overload of `Any()` already is](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#1165).

Comment: @svick: `MoveNext` isn't O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Properties should be used as a shortcut to define getters/setters. Since what you want cannot fit into concept of being a field with only getter, you should define it as a method so that another developer using your class knows that it will cost to call the method.

Another option is defining a real field called `NumEnabled` and then managing this field as you add/remove objects from the collection. Then you would define it as a property because it is a field now.

If you want to reflect any changes on an instance of MyObject class' Enabled field, then you should define an event that is raised when the object's Enabled value is changed. The collection should subscribe to this event, so that the collection can track when Enabled value is changed for every object in the collection. You can then manipulate the NumEnabled property to reflect any changes made to any object's Enabled field in the list.

```
class MyCollection<T>
{
    Int32 NumEnabled{get;private set;}

    ...

    void Add(T obj)
    {
        ... // Add the object here
        if(obj.Enabled)
        {
            this.NumEnabled++;
        }
    }

    void Remove(T obj)
    {
       ... // Remove the obj here
       if(obj.Enabled)
       {
           this.NumEnabled--;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using the `ObservableCollection` as the ItemSource of a `DataGrid`. Which additional methods would I need to override so that a change in the `MyObject` would be reflected in the `NumEnabled` property?

Comment: See my edit please. You should define an event that reports when its Enabled value is changed. This way collection can track each object's Enabled value.